# How to pass a prop to HOC in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

withLoader HOC component:

```
const withLoader = (WrappedComponent: any) => (props: any) => {
  if (props.loading) {
    return (
      <Styled.LoaderWrapper>
        <Styled.LoaderContent>
          <Styled.Fa icon={faSpinner} spin />
        </Styled.LoaderContent>
      </Styled.LoaderWrapper>
    );
  }
  return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
};

export default withLoader;
```

Login.tsx component:

```
const LoginPage = () => {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState<string>('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>('');

  const authUser = (): void => {
    dispatch(getJWT(login, password));
  };

  return (
    // markup goes here
  );
};

export default withLoader(LoginPage);
```

Now the thing i don't get. I want to show my loader (higher order component) when i dispatch my action in `authUser()`, like:

```
const authUser = (): void => {
  // there we start showing loader
  dispatch(getJWT(login, password)); // this action sends a POST request with credentials, then receives an access_token
  // there we end showing loader
};
```

How i do actually pass `loading` prop to my HOC?

Comment: What does your `getJWT` do? Assuming you're using redux, your action should dispatch in 3 cases: on request, on success, on failure. Then, your reducer can toggle the loading state to true on request, and false on success/failure. You should then connect your `withLoader(LoginPage)` component to the store to retrieve the loading state.

Comment: Well, but i'm calling my `LoginPage` component as Route in App.tsx: `<Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage}`, how do i apply loading state here?

Comment: `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withLoader(LoginPage))`